# Fastest way to convert Input Stream to a String in java

Tags: java, string, inputstream, apache-commons-io

There are many different ways to convert an `inputStream` to a `String` in java example `Guava`, `Apache Commons IO` and plain java like `scanner` class and  `ByteOutputStream`.
There are a lot of websites and question on stack overflow that show you how to do so. However I would like to know which is the fastest way especially when the `inpuStream` is very large.

Using a BufferedReader and reading each line and appending it to a string  in the manner below seems to be the most common approach but is very slow with large inputStreams

```
String inputLine;
            StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    response.append(inputLine);       
    }
            in.close();
```

Comment: Did you already use one of these solutions and did you experience it as being slow?

Comment: yes I used string builder and iterating through each Buffered line to append to a string which tends to be very slow when the line is large or there are a lot of lines.

Comment: If you want to read a large String you should initialize StringBuilder with an initial capacity: `new StringBuilder(1000000)` Best with the exact or slightly larger required capacity. This is speeding up the read process as no re-allocation have to be done.

Comment: @Robert what is the stringBuilder size unit? i.e. are the 1000000 you mentioned characters or physical memory size?

Comment: it's the capacity directly goes to an `char[capacity]` inside of StringBuilder. Every char in-memory is usually an UTF-16 character which means two bytes per character.